# How to install Folium in vscode on ipynb files on MacOS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython, folium

I have my VS code setup with Python and I also can run Jupyter Notebook Kernel inside of VS Code as well. Now when I Try to pip install folium on the same it give me ModuleNotFoundError.

How can I properly setup folium inside Vscode ?

Command I used to install

pip3 install folium

also folium shows up when I run python -m pip list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the following command on the Jupyter Notebook Cell to fix the issue.

`%pip install folium`

`%` makes sure you're installing it in the right environment while doing it through Jupyter Notebook itself.